# How to set preloadEnabled via chef?

Tags: iis, chef-infra

I am trying to set the iis 8.0 configuration `preloadEnabled` in my chef recipe, and i can't find the right combination of variables/attributes. I can't figure out how to specify the right application section [as defined in the IIS docs](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization), is the main problem. 
I do already have ApplicationInitialization enabled, with this block, that i've visually confirmed on the server:

```
windows_feature 'IIS-ApplicationInit' do
  action :install
end
```

I can open the `applicationHost.config` file listed in the iis docs, and i can see the app pools defined in there. But I can't seem to get my `preloadEnabled` attribute squeezed in there. This is the section I'm trying to access:

```
<system.applicationHost>
            <sites>
        <site name="MyApp" id="1">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="ProdApp">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
```

I'm trying to get the `application` section to look like this:  `<application path="/" preloadEnabled="true" applicationPool="ProdApp">`

My current code is:

```
iis_config '"myAppPoolName" -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools/sites/application/myAppPool/application /path="/" /preloadEnabled="true" /applicationPool="myAppPool" /commit:apphost'
```

After some more iterations and searching I've got this - still doesn't work:

```
  '"MyApp"  /path:"MyApp" /section:sites /preloadEnabled:true /commit:apphost'
```

(Answers to this could inform answers to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836834/how-set-value-property-preloadenabled-to-directoryentry-in-iis-with-c-sharp))

Comment: Ok! [This command worked!](https://forums.iis.net/t/1196037.aspx?Using+Appcmd+to+set+preloadEnabled+true) Now i have to get it into the recipe. 

    `appcmd.exe set app "MyApp/" /preloadEnabled:true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it!

`execute 'preloadEnabled' do
  command 'c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "MyApp/" /preloadEnabled:true'
end`